# Do we have different close voting/off topic question policies depending on language tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, vote-to-close

I'd come along [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232832/how-to-not-fadeout-inner-and-outer-div-when-outer-div-click-is-fadeout) by chance (it's not any of my favorite viewed language tags), and wondered if it could be that we seemingly have completely different voting culture dependent on programming language/operating system/framework tags?

With e.g the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag , such kind of questions, not showing the code and/or further explanation what's going wrong in particular with the posted code (no matter if any off-source link is given), won't be accepted as valid usually.

What makes up the difference, can anyone explain?

Comment: Given that most major language tags are going to have different users, why is it so unexpected that they will evaluate post differently?

Comment: Every major tag has culture differences.  Some upvote more, some less.  Some are more strict with certain close vote reasons.  Some will upvote/downvote based on programming philosophy differences that correlate with language.  Its really expected behavior when you have a very fractured userbase like this.  That doesn't mean that if you go to another tag for a post or two you shouldn't use your own best judgement on voting and try to conform, it does mean don't be surprised if people act differently.

Comment: In many tags there are some who will answer anything anyone might post, irrespective of what kind of garbage it is. And there are those who will upvote anything too.... And many of the javascript guys, especially the jquery ones, seem to think jsfiddle is part of this site...

Comment: I also see this a lot that there is a **huge** difference between tags/languages how questions gets handled, like I see many users answering c questions no matter how many dupes there are or even if the **same** user answered the **exact** same question already just earlier in the day. So for me as an example I don't see anyone who really cares about dupes/closing in the C tag where it is completely different in the php tag

Comment: Well, there's the long tail tag culture.  No matter how the gawdforsaken bad the question, nothing *ever* gets closed.

Comment: C++ developers work with a hateful unforgiving language all day and it rubs off on them.